# Ubuntu 16.04, ethernet connection only present one time after inserting the graphic card

Tags: 16.04, internet, ethernet

I have an issue concerning Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and the internet connection. In general, it is impossible to connect the PC to the internet. I tried to use `lspci`, `ifconfig` or `lshw -C network` and nowhere are information about my ethernet module. It seems like it is not present.

The only way the internet works is after unplugging the GPU and plugging it in again (of course, the power and the monitors are also unplugged during this process). `lspci`, `ifconfig` or `lshw -C network` return afterwards correct values.

After rebooting the system, the internet does not work again.

This is a weird behavior and I do not know how to handle this inconvenience. Therefore, I hope somebody has an idea what to do.